# Jquery Datatable: Data won't load using ajax

Tags: ajax, vb.net, datatables

This is my first time using Jquery datatable.

I don't know what's wrong with my code, but the data won't load into the datatable.
Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TestDPRDetail.aspx/GetdtbScenario",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#grvScenario').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns:
                    [
                        { "data": "SCENARIO_ID" }
                    ]
                });
            },
        });


    });
```

The url: TestDPRDetail.aspx/GetdtbScenario returns a datatable json serialized object

```
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetdtbScenario() As Object
    Dim dtbScenarioTemp As New DataTable
    Dim strDPR_ID As String
    Dim clsScenarioBusiness As New ScenarioBusiness
    Dim json As Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

    strDPR_ID = "DPR-201807-00001"
    dtbScenarioTemp = clsScenarioBusiness.GetdtbScenario(strDPR_ID) 'getting data from sql

    Return json.SerializeObject(dtbScenarioTemp)
End Function
```

I checked with a normal method (using array object) to load the datatable, it works fine:

```
 var dataTemp = [{ "SCENARIO_ID": "SCN-201807-00008", "SCENARIO #": "B", "SCENARIO NAME": "Test Inquiry", "CONDITION": "Negative" }]

        $('#grvScenario').dataTable({
            data: dataTemp,
            columns: [
                {"data":"SCENARIO_ID"}
            ]
        });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="grvScenario">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Scenario ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Is there something i missed from the ajax or datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize datatables first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#grvScenario').dataTable({
    ajax: "TestDPRDetail.aspx/GetdtbScenario",
    columns: [
      { "data": "SCENARIO_ID" }
    ]
  })

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried this before getting my answer, but it gives an error. I forgot what, but the jquery datatable won't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, i've got my answer

It seems that TestDPRDetail.aspx/GetdtbScenario was returning a different json object after ajax call.

The return variable (data) needs to be parsed again in javascript. So it will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TestDPRDetail.aspx/GetdtbScenario",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#grvScenario').dataTable({
                data: JSON.parse(data.d),
                columns:
                [
                    { "data": "SCENARIO_ID" }
                ]
            });
        },
    });
```

Hope it will help anyone having the same issue